# Update ids in mySQL database when deleting a row with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a data table with 3 columns: index, title, message. Example:

```
1    'Title1'    'Hi!'
2    'Title2'    'Sup'
3    'Title3'    'Nothing'
```

If I delete for example the middle one, the index numbers will contain a gap. How can I update them to fix this? Is there any mysql preference for this? (I really need them to be in order, with no gaps)

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't think of the simplest: id=id-1 where the id is larger than the deleted id. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this automatically with a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_indexes AFTER DELETE on your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        your_table
    SET
        your_table.`index` = your_table.`index` - 1
    WHERE your_table.`index` > old.`index`;
END
```